# using modal for each item in a list in yii framework

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

There is a list of patient data using a "TbGridView" widget,

Now, I want to use modal widget for each one of the patient here, so, that 
the patient id is passed to the modal for each patient with patient id.

I had tried this, but, I am being unable to pass each patient id to the modal form.
Any response related to this would be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no direct way of doing that I mean that you cant render dynamic data by passing an id. Modal is static.
You can use ajax call for that to retrieve data from database and render that data in your modal. Follow these steps 
 
1. In your gridview use `rowHtmlOptionsExpression` to set id for specific row.
2. create an action in your controller to handle ajax call.
3. use jquery click event on TbGridView elements like

```
$('#mygrid table tbody tr td:not(:first-child)').on('click', function() {
            var Url =<?php echo '"' . CController::createUrl('/user/default/viewMessageAjax') . '"'; ?>;
            var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
            console.log($(this));

            $.ajax({
                url: Url,
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.modal-body').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        })
        jQuery('#mygrid >table>tbody>tr:first-child').live('click', function() {
            return false;
        })
```

above code is just an example, you can change it according to ur needs.